# Git status change

Tags: git, macos, directory, repository

I accidentally pushed all my system to git directory and now it wants to commit all the files on my Mac which made a huge mess on my computer. Any idea how can I change the directory and get rid of this mess? when I open VS code, there are more than 5k files waiting to commit

Comment: try running ```git rev-parse --git-dir``` to detect where the git directory is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the **.git** folder from your directory.
You can view the hidden folder in finder using the below shortcut:
**CMD + Shift + .**

The .git directory is what tells the system that this is a git repository.
Hope this is what you were asking.